# Terminate shell script using PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm trying to terminate a shell script using PHP code.

I have created a shell script `foo.sh` which calls a PHP file

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /var/www/html/test
php test.php
```

Following is test.php

```
<?php
  exec('exit 0');
?>
```

For some reason the shell script is not exiting.

Comment: Wil `test.php` take a long time to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `exit(0)` in PHP will terminate process with PHP itself, and not parent process (if any).
To terminate your bash script, you will need to find it's pid via `ps` and `grep`, or, alternatively, use `killall`:

```
system('killall foo.sh');
```

-in PHP

Comment: if PID of foo.sh is 2710 my code should be like `system('killall 2710');` or `system('killall foo.sh');`?

Comment: `killall` takes prosess __name__ - and so there's no sense to pass pid there. To say more, your pid will be new each time, while `killall` is intended to kill process independent of it's pid

Comment: However, the proper way to do this is to cooperate with the caller. For example, `php test.php || exit $?` will exit with the exit code of the PHP script if it's non-zero, and continue otherwise.

Comment: I agree that it's normal way, while OP's question may be more common (for example, he has not control over parent script)